# Git tfs clone - Server was unable to process request. ---> There was an error generating the XML document. ---> Specified cast not valid

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc, git-tfs

I was trying to migrate tfs to git using `git tfs clone` command:

```
git tfs clone https://locahost/collection $/"Test project/feature-branch"
```

Error received:

> 2019-10-31 12:39:56.8412 [Debug]
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> There was an error generating the XML document.
>   ---> Specified cast is not valid.    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.LoadWorkItem(Int32
>   id, Int32 rev, Nullable`1 asof, IWorkItemRowSets& witem)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem..ctor(WorkItemStore
>   store, Uri uri)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Changeset.get_WorkItems()
>   at GitTfs.VsCommon.TfsHelperBase.BuildTfsChangeset(Changeset
>   changeset, IGitTfsRemote remote)    at
>   GitTfs.VsCommon.TfsHelperBase.<GetChangesets>d__46.MoveNext()    at
>   GitTfs.Core.GitTfsRemote.FetchWithMerge(Int32 mergeChangesetId,
>   Boolean stopOnFailMergeCommit, Int32 lastChangesetIdToFetch,
>   IRenameResult renameResult, String[] parentCommitsHashes)    at
>   GitTfs.Core.GitTfsRemote.Fetch(Boolean stopOnFailMergeCommit, Int32
>   lastChangesetIdToFetch, IRenameResult renameResult)    at
>   GitTfs.Commands.Fetch.DoFetch(IGitTfsRemote remote, Boolean
>   stopOnFailMergeCommit)    at GitTfs.Commands.Fetch.FetchRemote(Boolean
>   stopOnFailMergeCommit, IGitTfsRemote remote)    at
>   GitTfs.Commands.Fetch.Run(Boolean stopOnFailMergeCommit, String[]
>   args)    at GitTfs.Commands.Fetch.Run()    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>
>   at GitTfs.Util.GitTfsCommandRunner.Run(GitTfsCommand command, IList`1
>   args)    at GitTfs.GitTfs.Main(GitTfsCommand command, IList`1
>   unparsedArgs)    at GitTfs.GitTfs.Run(IList`1 args)    at
>   GitTfs.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: Hi Uday, Did you get a chance to implement the solution that  Daniel suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Hi Patrick, it migrates around 180k changeset and then it gets stuck at a certain changeset with the above error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a typo:

`$/"Test project/feature-branch"`

You should wrap the entire source control path in quotation marks: `"$/Test project/feature-branch"`

Comment: Hi Daniel, it migrates around 180k changeset and then it gets stuck at a single changeset with the above error

Comment: Yes, I tried wrapping sourcepath in double-quotes. but, it's failing.